# Expected cardinal of the intersection between a random subset and a fixed subset

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

I have a set of size $n$, and a fixed subset $A$ of cardinal $k$. I take a random subset $X$ of cardinal $d$. I need to compute the expected cardinal of the intersection between $A$ and $X$.

I tried the following: the probability that the intersection is of cardinal $i$ (for $i$ in $[\max(0, n-k-d), \min(k,d)]$) is:

$$
\mathbf{P}(|X\cap A|=i)=\frac{\binom{k}{i}\binom{n-k}{d-i}}{\binom{n}{d}}
$$

I just choose the intersection, $i$ elements in $A$, then the $d-i$ remaining elements in the complementary. But now the expected value is:

$$
\mathbf{E}(|X\cap A|)=\frac{1}{\binom{n}{d}}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{d}i\binom{k}{i}\binom{n-k}{d-i}
$$

and I don't know what to do from here. I'd like to use Vandermonde identity, but I don't know how to deal with the $i$ in the sum. Am I missing something ?

Thanks !

Comment: Write $i{k\choose i}=k{k-1\choose i-1}$ and you can use Vandermonde.

Comment: Oh thanks ! Sorry for the silly question...

Answer (score 3):

Your approach yields
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=0}^d i \binom{k}{i} \binom{n-k}{d-i}}{\binom{n}{d}}
= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^d k \binom{k-1}{i-1} \binom{n-k}{d-i}}{\binom{n}{d}}
= k \frac{\binom{n-1}{d-1}}{\binom{n}{d}}
= k \frac{\binom{n-1}{d-1}}{\frac{n}{d}\binom{n-1}{d-1}}
= \frac{k d}{n}.
$$

---

An alternative approach is to let $X=\{x_1,\dots,x_d\} \subset \{1,\dots,n\}$ and introduce indicator random variables $X_j$ for $j\in\{1,\dots,d\}$:
$$X_j =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x_j\in A$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Then
$$
E[|X\cap A|]
= E\left[\sum_{j=1}^d X_j\right]
= \sum_{j=1}^d E\left[X_j\right]
= \sum_{j=1}^d P[x_j \in A]
= \sum_{j=1}^d \frac{k}{n}
= \frac{dk}{n}.
$$